# Gitlab CI not recognizing the ng command

Tags: angular, git, gitlab-ci

I am new to GitLab CI/CD. I have been trying to just run an angular project. I have added a yml script which has some basic echos, and I installed packages through npm installed, which didn't show any errors. But when the ng serve was run, there came an error showing.

> Error
>
> ```
> ng is not recognized
> ```

Then I tried installing angular CLI using npm, which showed no errors. But again when the ng serve ran, there came an error.
Could anyone please suggest where am I missing the ng?
[image: This is the Error shown]

[image: This is the yml script]

Comment: `ng` is not loaded on boot, you must point where npm install install it `./path/node_modules/xxx/ng serve -o --port`

Answer (score 0):

if your env variable for NODE_ENV is set to production, you have to install the angular cli with --save-dev.

npm install @angular/cli@16.1.4 --save-dev